# Scraping Data on TradingView with BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]I just started learning web scraping and decided to scrape the daily value from this site:

https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/INDEX-MMTW/

I am using BeautifulSoup and then doing inspect element and then Copy -> CSS Selector.

However, the returned items are always 0 length. I tried the select() method (from ATBS) and find() method.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the code...

```
import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/INDEX-MMTW/')
res.raise_for_status()
nmmtw_data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')


(Instead of writing the selector yourself, you can also right-click on the element in your browser
and select Inspect Element. When the browser’s developer console opens, right-click on the element’s
HTML and select Copy ▸ CSS Selector to copy the selector string to the clipboard and paste it into your
source code.)

elems = nmmtw_data.select("div.js-symbol-last > span:nth-child(1)")

new_try = nmmtw_data.find(class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last")

print(type(new_try))
print(len(new_try))


print(elems)
print(type(elems))
print(len(elems))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you refine the Q further. Its unclear. Which element on this website corresponds to "daily market value"? It'll help others if you can post a screenshot of the webpage element that you want.

Comment: @mnm I added a picture. I get the value at end of day after market already closed.

Comment: @mnm have you had a chance to look at this yet? tia!                                                                      https://stackoverflow.com/users/4195053/mnm

Comment: i think its not as easy as it seems in first glance. The number that you want is dynamically generated by the javascript coding wrapped around the html soup

Comment: that sucks. any idea if this page is possible?
https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$MMTW/interactive-chart

Comment: if you can figure out the javascript rendering, then certainly its possible.

Comment: any idea where to start on how to scrape javascript?

Comment: ok. thanks i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since the price table is generated with JavaScript, unfortunately, we cannot simply use BeautifulSoup to scrape the pricing table. Instead, you should use web browser automation framework.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found the solution so far, but if not, I believe the answer to your problems is using selenium module. Additionally, you need to install the webdriver specific to the browser you're using. I think BeautifulSoup is very limited these days because most of the sites are generated using java script.

All the info that you need for selenium you can find here:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @mnikola342. I ended up using barchart.com and it seems to work with beautiful soup